# binance api + python , как открыть/создать ордер по фьючерсам

Tags: python

```
api_key = "xxx"
api_secret = "xxxx"

from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
import math

client = Client(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)

symbol_info = client.get_symbol_info('AKROUSDT')
print(symbol_info)

# создание ордера (на покупку/buy_limit крипты "AKROUSDT" по цене 0.02, кредит.плечо = 10
# обьем покупки = 1.50005000)
result_3 = client.futures_create_order(symbol="AKROUSDT", side="BUY", type="LIMIT", price=0.02,
                                       quantity=1.50005000, timeInForce="GTC", leverage=10)
print(result_3)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PS:** *за вознаграждение (необходим работающий код для создания ордера buy/sell_limit по любой криптовалюте с нужными параметрами обьем ордера / цена актива / тип ордера / плечо )*

Comment: написано же "точность превышает максимум, определенный для этого объекта". значит quantity неверное количество после запятой, либо в price.

Comment: вот с binance AKROUSDT=0.02921. следовательно 5 знаков после запятой

Comment: данная ошибка сначала на пару минут не появлялась (в этот минут появилась другая ошибка связанная со timestamp), потом снова появилась и сохраняется :/

Comment: сначала подумал после вашего замечания что ошибка исчезла и появилась другая , но потом через короткое время снова появилась и остается до сих пор

Comment: timestamp я тоже решал. надо просто перехватывать эту ошибку, создавать новый timestamp и отправлять запрос снова

Comment: попробуйте купить продать с type="MARKET", если ошибки не будет, значит все таки ошибка в не правильных цифрах

Comment: Все нашел наобходимо в quantity тип не float , а int !!! Спасибо